# Wix - Burn tool - How to notify error or failure due to non-vital package in the chain

Tags: wix, burn, chain

In my wix bundle I have chain of multiple Packages (see below), out of those if my App2 fails to install still I need to continue with the rest of the installation but at the end would like to show failure message reported by App2 package. Any suggestion on how to implement this?

```
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />
    <Chain>
        <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
        <!-- <MsiPackage SourceFile="path\to\your.msi" /> -->
  <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx462Web"/>
  <MsiPackage Id="App1" SourceFile="App1.msi" DisplayInternalUI='yes' Compressed ="yes"  />
  <RollbackBoundary />
  **<MsiPackage Id="App2" SourceFile="App2.msi" Permanent="yes" Visible="yes" DisplayInternalUI='no' Vital='no' Compressed ="yes" />**
  <PackageGroupRef Id="App3"/>
  <PackageGroupRef Id="App4" />
</Chain>
```